# Android databinding with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-databinding, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm trying to use data binding with my class which now looks like this

```
public class Task extends BaseObservable {
ObservableField<String> name;
ObservableField<String> description;
ObservableField<String> start;
ObservableField<String> end;
ObservableField<String> endTime;
ObservableInt urgency;
ObservableField<String> uid;

public Task(){
    uid.set(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}

public Task(String name, String Desc, String Start, String End, String time, int urgency){
    this.name.set(name);
    this.description.set(Desc);
    this.start.set(Start);
    this.end.set(End);
    this.endTime.set(time);
    this.urgency.set(urgency);
    uid.set(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description.get();
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description.set(description);
}

public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}

public String getEndTime() {
    return endTime.get();
}

public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
    this.endTime.set(endTime);
}

public String getStart() {
    return start.get();
}

public void setStart(String start) {
    this.start.set(start);
}

public String getEnd() {
    return end.get();
}

public void setEnd(String end) {
    this.end.set(end);
}

public int getUrgency() {
    return urgency.get();
}

public void setUrgency(int urgency) {
    this.urgency.set(urgency);
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid.get();
}
```

but I'm also using Firebase to store and retrieve my data and when I'm pulling data back I'm getting

```
Task t = dataSnapshot.getValue(Task.class);


com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a Map while deserializing, but got a class java.lang.String
```

is it possible to use Observable fields with Firebase? I get that Observable Field might not be serializable but my getters and setters all take and return either strings or ints

Comment: but my getters and setters do take and return serializeable types

Comment: not sure of `BaseObservable` class inner properties though. pretty sure the solution posted here would work for you.